# Megabloks need help identifying what set

Tags: part-identification, set-identification, clone-brands

On the bottom it says mega bloks I tried finding any type of castle with it I don't see anything can anyone identify it please [image]

Comment: There isn't a good central parts database for the clone brand parts, but the folks on this site have been able to answer this sort of question in a few prior cases.  Have you tried a reverse image search?

Comment: I have and I'm not finding anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a part of the tower from

[Set # 3618 : Privateer's Lighthouse](http://www.blokcity.com/wiki/index.php?title=3618_Privateers%27_Lighthouse)

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much